# IMU Message Error

Tags: imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I thought I would try and generate and IMU message for the gyro that's on my robot to feed into the laser_scan_matcher (To be honest as it's quite slow to update I'm not sure if it'll be of much use).

Anyway the LSM is complaining with an error "MSG to TF: Quaternion Not Properly Normalized" so I guess I have message the message up.

The gyro only measures rotation so that end I have set the co-matrix's zeroth element to -1 for the angular_velocity_covariance and linear_acceleration_covarianc parts. (as per http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html)

The message I'm outputting is (338 degres):

```
header: 
  seq: 3734
  stamp: 
    secs: 1459073468
    nsecs: 76810552
  frame_id: imu_msg
orientation: 
  x: 5.89921283722
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
  w: 0.0
orientation_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular_velocity_covariance: [-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
linear_acceleration: 
 x: 0.0
 y: 0.0
 z: 0.0
linear_acceleration_covariance: [-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
```

What do I need to correct?

Many thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230241/imu-message-error/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2016-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your problem is that the "Quaternion [is] Not Properly Normalized". A Quaternion (your rotation) must have a norm of 1

```
 x**2+y**2+z**2+w**2==1
```

which is obviously not true for your quaternion. You can use these functions to create a valid quaternion from RPY: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Overview/Data%20Types

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2016-03-27**:
Thanks - what do I call to get the normalized component parts back - i.e so I can set:

```
tf::Quaternion q  = tf::createQuaternionFromRPY(degree_to_radian(pRobotData->GyroOrientation),0, 0);

imu_msg.orientation.x = q.x;
imu_msg.orientation.y = q.y;
imu_msg.orientation.z = q.z; etc...
```

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-03-27**:
That looks ok. What kind of robot do you have? I would have expected that you'd measure the yaw angle.

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2016-03-27**:
This was the compilation error:

rror: cannot convert ‘tf::QuadWord::x’ from type ‘const tfScalar& (tf::QuadWord::)() const {aka const double& (tf::QuadWord::)() const}’ to type ‘geometry_msgs::Quaternion_std::allocator<void >::_x_type {aka double}’
imu_msg.orientation.x = q.x;

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2016-03-27**:
The imu message is defined as:

sensor_msgs::Imu imu_msg;

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-03-27**:
If you read the message carefully, you could find the "aka const double& (tf::QuadWord::)() const". (Note the '()' ). q.x is a function that returns the x component, so you have to write `imu_msg.orientation.x = q.x();`   (Check L74 in http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf/html/c++/QuadWord_8h_source.html

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2016-03-27**:
Good point :) Thanks for your help!